# Dynamically inject service to a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-injector

Instead of specifying all the services in a controller like:

```
mainApp.controller('MultiController', ['$scope', '$attrs', '$branchesService', '$repositoriesService', function ($scope, $attrs, $branchesService, $repositoriesService) {
console.log('multiController instantiated');
var vm = this;

// private idu funkcija definition bez scope
vm.init = function(mod) {
    vm.mod = mod;
    if (mod == "branch") {
        console.log('MultiController branchesService');
        vm.service = $branchesService;
    } else {
        console.log('MultiController repoService');
        vm.service = $repositoriesService;
    }

    vm.items = [];
    vm.selectedItem = null;
    vm.error = 'no Error at the moment...';

    loadRemoteData();
    console.log('multiController.init()');
}
vm.init($attrs.mod);
```

Is it possible to use $inject ?
I am using $attrs to get a spec from html, which service should I use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [**`$injector`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector) dependency inside your controller and then do `$injector.get` to get service object.

> `$injector` is used to retrieve object instances as defined by provider,
>   instantiate types, invoke methods, and load modules.

Basically `$injector.get` method will search for whichever service name you provide inside angular `context` & return the `object` if its found.

**Code**

```
vm.init = function(mod) {
    vm.mod = mod;
    if (mod == "branch") {
        console.log('MultiController branchesService');
        vm.service = $injector.get('branchesService'); //you will have service instance here
    } else {
        console.log('MultiController repoService');
        vm.service = $injector.get('repositoriesService'); //you will have service instance here
    }

    vm.items = [];
    vm.selectedItem = null;
    vm.error = 'no Error at the moment...';

    loadRemoteData();
    console.log('multiController.init()');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can inject `$injector`, and use it like this:

```
var brancesService = $injector.get('brancesService');
```